# How to bind to self?

Tags: wpf, xaml, data-binding, datatrigger

I know `RelativeSource Self` binds to the `DataContext` in scope.  That is not what I want.  I have a `TextBlock` and I want to set a trigger which will multibind 2 things.  A value from my `DataContext/ViewModel` which is easy and I have done that.  The 2nd value I want is the Text property of the `TextBlock`.  I can't seem to get the syntax at all.

I have this trigger in a TextBlock style.

```
<Style TargetType="TextBlock"}">
    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="10"></Setter>
    <Style.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Value="True">
            <DataTrigger.Binding>
                <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource CustomMultiValueConverter}">
                    <Binding Path="SelectedCategory"></Binding>
                    <Binding Path="Text" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Self}"></Binding>
                </MultiBinding>
            </DataTrigger.Binding>
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Blue"></Setter>
        </DataTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

Comment: Post your code/xaml, so people can help you.

Comment: `RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Self}"` will bind to TextBlock only.

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong.... but that is exactly what I have is it not?  And I can't get to the Text property... plus it tells me that Self is the DataContext of the window - i.e. my view model

Comment: @Shumii [The WPF Cheat sheet is a really great and compact paper about binding](http://www.nbdtech.com/Free/WpfBinding.pdf). Could you post the code for your converter?

Comment: Hi Stian - the converter does nothing.  I use it to debug to see if the right value is sent over from my 2nd binding.  It simply returns null, but execution doesn't get that far as I terminate the process when i find the value passed through is nothing.

Comment: Have you tried removing the converter entirely?  If you're returning null (and interrupting the conversion), the actual value never gets back to the UI.  The value converter is eating your value.

Comment: It doesn't get that far.  When the value is passed to the converter that is where my test case ends.  It never returns anything.  I need the value passed through to the converter to be my TextBlock's text value.  That's it.

Comment: `Text` will be null in case you haven't set it. It works definitely (tried in small sample as well). Post some code here to replicate your issue.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use a [`RelativeSource.AncestorType`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.relativesource.ancestortype(v=vs.110).aspx) `Binding` to reach the `TextBlock.Text` value. Try this:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="10"></Setter>
    <Style.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Value="True">
            <DataTrigger.Binding>
                <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource CustomMultiValueConverter}">
                    <Binding Path="SelectedCategory"></Binding>
                    <Binding Path="Text" RelativeSource="{Binding RelativeSource 
                        AncestorType={x:Type TextBlock}}" />
                </MultiBinding>
            </DataTrigger.Binding>
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Blue"></Setter>
        </DataTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```